# Unresolved external calling C function from C++

Tags: c++, c, linker, unresolved-external

I have a Visual Studio solution which has to call legacy C code from C++ code and I am getting linker errors.  Eg:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: testapp_soln, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>legacy.lib(launchit.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl legacy_task(void)" (?legacy_task@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall Launchit::DoIt(void)" (?DoIt@Launchit@@UAEXXZ)
1>E:\share\code\so\TestApp\testapp_soln\Debug\testapp_soln.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have a static lib project called legacy with a C++ class, launchit calling the C functions in legacy C code.

Here are details of the legacy project.

legacy.h:

```
#ifndef LEGACY_H_
#define LEGACY_H_

extern void legacy_task (void);

extern int initialise_thing();

#endif /* LEGACY_H_ */
```

legacy.c

```
#include "legacy.h"

void legacy_task (void)
{
  /* doing things */
  initialise_thing();
}
```

legacy_init.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int initialise_thing()
{
  printf("Doing init thing here\n");
  return 0;
}
```

legacy C stuff called from launchit class

launchit.hpp

```
#ifndef LAUNCHIT_HPP_
#define LAUNCHIT_HPP_

class Launchit
{
public:
    Launchit();
    virtual ~Launchit();
    virtual void DoIt();
};

#endif // LAUNCHIT_HPP_
```

launchit.cpp

```
#include "Launchit.hpp"
#include "legacy.h"

Launchit::Launchit() 
{
}

Launchit::~Launchit()
{
```

### }

```
void Launchit::DoIt()
{
    legacy_task();
}
```

Then I build this as a static lib.  It build just fine.

I have a console application project like this:

```
#include "launchit.hpp"

int main() {
    Launchit li;
    li.DoIt();
}
```

But this gives me linker error:

```
legacy.lib(launchit.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl legacy_task(void)" (?legacy_task@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall Launchit::DoIt(void)" (?DoIt@Launchit@@UAEXXZ)
```

How can I fix this linker error?

Comment: You need the extern "C" bit

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Notice that the link error says that the symbol `?legacy_task@@YAXXZ` was not found. This is a mingled name, derived by the C++ compiler from the function name. For compatibility with C, you need to use "extern "C" in `legacy.h`:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
   void legacy_task (void);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

This way, the compiler does not mangle the funtion's name.

For a detailed discussion of `extern "C"`, see [In C++ source, what is the effect of extern "C"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c)

Comment: As that header is used in .c `extern "C"` should be `#ifdef` for C++

Comment: Yep. Added now. Thanks!

Comment: Just tried surrounding both C functions with #ifdef __cplusplus and that works

Comment: Sorry, only needed for legacy_task func

Comment: Albeit that this is a duplicate, this is a very nice answer.

Comment: Tried with this(surrounding with extern c) didnt worked, Actually c code code in another project in same solution(vs2015) and I am calling from cpp function project, please let me know any other things to check.